# Best strategies to protect Query String in membership site?

Tags: database, security

Let's say you have 3 tables:

```
User        Blog        Post

UserId      BlogId      PostId
Username    BlogName    PostTitle
            UserId      BlogId
```

Let's say now the Blog Owner tries to visit `EditPost.aspx?ID=51`. How do you protect this query string so that only the original Blog Owner sees the real post. Eg. A user Jon doesn't start editing user Mary's post?

A couple of options I have:

**1)** I encrypt the query string which is obviously not 100% secure but does the job.

**2)** I check everytime whether PostID that is in query string is indeed the logged in user's Post by checking it against the UserID that I have in Session. The disadvantage to this is this is OK if I have just 3 tables but if I have a hierarchy of tables with 10-12 tables in relation and I have the UserID in 1st table and I am actually querying for 12th table, I need to check all the way back to the top by making 12 joins to actually see whether that thing is "really" his or not.

Question is which one of these do you really use in your site and does the job good?

Comment: You already know the answer: 2.  You may want to create views in your database to hide some of the joins.

Comment: Why don't you check the **user** and **role** against the post before render the page?? also try to be specific about technology that you using when you do tagging

Comment: @humpty dumpty sat on the wall: Understand that this isn't a technology specific question. This is general web development concept that any developer in any technology would have faced.

Comment: if you need 12 joins to validate user credentials, it means you need to re design your database.

Comment: @itachi: The databases that I have worked with have even 800 tables. 12 joins are nothing. You need to redesign your way of thinking.

Comment: -1 for the attitude. plus, had you been polite, i would have offered a simpler approach provided you wrote the scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string doesn't need to be encrypted, you just need server-side checks anytime your render or data is posted to you.

Your security checks are fine.  If you have 12 joins to get to your data, I'd say re-architect your data model or store the user foreign key in more places.

Comment: Storing foreign key is multiple tables? Doesn't that violate normal forms rule? In this case the Post's BlogID would never be changed. But what would happen when such an ID can be changed? Should I then remember and update those keys in multiple tables?

Comment: Yes, but the database can cascade...etc if need be, this really isn't the place to go over that, but there are tons of database architectures that meet different data model needs.

Answer (score 2):

In order to control editing of the record, you need to know who owns it.

Approach #1 is flawed since it may be vulnerable to replay attacks, or more to the point, it assumes that if the user has successfully navigated to the page, that they are authorized.  This is "security through obscurity" and is a big no-no.

Approach #2 is your only real option.  If you are concerned about the number of joins to tie PostID to UserID, you should post a new question about optimizing your query (and provide more information about the query and specific db structure).